# Alternative for VrPanoramaView since it is deprecated

Tags: android, sdk, components, 360-virtual-reality

I would like to built a small app that shows a panorama 360º image with head tracking on Android. I quickly stumbled upon com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.**VrPanoramaView** (https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/android/vrview). But there is a big disclaimer on top:

> This site has been archived and remains strictly as a historical reference for developers who actively maintain apps built using the legacy Google VR SDK, which was last updated in 2019 and is no longer receiving updates. All developers actively developing experiences for Google Cardboard should use the new open source Cardboard SDKs for iOS, Android NDK, and Unity XR Plugin.

So clicking the link to the new Cardboard SDK I ended up here: https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/c/quickstart

Which shows a game like environment in stereo VR. Super cool in its own right, but it isn't a replacement for VrPanoramaView. And the newer SDKs for Android do not support VrPanoramaView anymore.

Also, I could not find an example on the new Cardboard SDK site how to built a 'simple' VR image 360º panorama viewer with headtracking.

Googling a bit more I found that people said there is no alternative for the deprecated panorama VR viewer, which I find hard to understand. The VrPanoramaView seemed pretty simple and elegant in its use, whereas going full blown C++ with matrices and all for lens distortion seems like pretty hard core to deal with to me. Compare all that C++ code to this much simpeler code example: https://youtu.be/gnDa-fvEyUk?t=471

Is there an out-of-the-box VR 360º image viewer that supports stereo? Or how could I use the new Cardboard SDK and built something similar?

Comment: Same issue, If you find any solution Bro plz inform us.

Comment: @DhavalSolanki I did not and gave up 